# google.com redirected after xpressconnect installed

Tags: wi-fi, networking

I'm using Android 2.3 on Nook Color (ROM CyanogenMod). I installed xpressconnect to connect to the wifi network of my school, and successfully configured it. I can access the internet normally. However, when I go home and use my home wifi, all web addresses work, except *.google.com. Every time I go to *.google.com, it gets redirected to the configuration web page of my school, and it's permanent (not because of the cache). So all google services on my nook are not working. I checked /etc/hosts and it's empty. I don't know how to fix this problem. Will I have to factory reset my nook?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed the problem by the following steps:

1. Clear data of the xpressconnect app, then uninstall it.  This step alone didn't fix the problem.
2. Reboot my nook to recovery mode, and clear/wipe the Dalvik cache.
3. Restart.

To start fresh, I also clear the cache of all my web browsers.